# Azure webapp backup fails

Tags: azure, backup

I have a webapp scaled at S3 Standard with 50GB storage. Trying to setup a backup and ran a manual backup but failed saying "The website + database size exceeds the 10 GB limit for backups. Your content size is 15.9 GB."  Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-backup/).
The maximum backup size is 10gb.
You can scale up to premium but the max backup size will stay the same. Half way through the article they describe how to exclude files/folders from the backup (if that helps).